# How to display emoji in ShareLatex?

Tags: unicode, sharelatex

I have followed the instructions, primarily starting with choosing the compiler to be XeLaTeX.  The example at:

[ShareLaTeX XeLaTeX example](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/XeLaTeX)

provides instructions but it doesn't work for the emoji at the end of this line:

913 INTEREST

that's unicode 0001F913 if it doesn't render on your browser (it does for me)

I uploaded menlo.ttc from my mac since this works in Sublime and Sublime is using that font.  Here's a picture of what I get (you can see the  document is successfully in menlo:

[image: screenshot of my ShareLaTeX attempt]

Please, for specific reasons I need to be on ShareLaTeX so if you could just test that your answer works there I would be grateful.

Comment: I don't think either luatex or xetex support the new coloured emoji font formats yet, so you need to include them as images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the font formats are not (yet?) supported by luatex and xetex but you can get access to the emoji as images, for example the emojione site makes all the emoji in that font available as SVG which can easily be converted to pdf.

Once you have a pdf of each one then

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

zzz \includegraphics[height=1em]{1f913.pdf} zzz

\end{document}
```

[image]

The emojione images are available as svg or png here

http://emojione.com/developers/

Comment: I understand what you are saying about luatex and xetex but it is my understanding that XeLaTeX does support full unicode, I just can't seem to get it to work with ShareLatex.

Comment: @mcwizard it is not an issue with _unicode_  xetex understands your unicode input, it's an issue with _opentype_ the emoji fonts use an extended version of opentype (one of two extension) emojione for example has the glyphs all as svg internally, so existing systems simply do not recognise the font as a font.

Comment: There is at least one package to simplify that, of course: https://github.com/benjamin-weiss/emojione-latex Not in CTAN, though.

Comment: The emojione-latex package referenced by @Crissov has over 1600 individual pdfs, which exceeds the limits on number of files per project of any of the Overleaf plans. (Overleaf is the successor to ShareLaTeX.) [What is the maximum compilation time, file number and project size allowed on free vs paid plans?](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_is_the_maximum_compilation_time,_file_number_and_project_size_allowed_on_free_vs_paid_plans%3F)